# How to make a dynamic float variable which is first embedded in a user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

TL;DR - The variable *importFunc* as defined in the first block of code is supposed to be a user input function expressed in terms of *x*, another variable which is supposed to be manipulated later in the *for loop* in the second block of code. This doesn't work, resulting in a *TypeError*. How do I create a dynamic variable *x* such that I can manipulate *inputFunc* like in the *for loop*?

I'm currently learning python as my first coding language (not counting excel). My current project is an attempt to make a Riemman Sum calculator, including right, left, and diagonal Riemann Sums. As shown below, it strives to take some user input function in terms of *x* and output a Riemann Sum given the user's selected criteria.

```
import math

x = 0. #can be any arbitrary float

"""inputs"""
inputFunc = input("Input a function in terms of x\n")

inputStart = float(input("Input start of range: "))
inputEnd = float(input("Input end of range: "))
inputSum = float(input("Input number of total summations over range: "))

inputChoice = input("Input type of Riemann approximation.\n[Left/Right/Diagonal]\n")
```

Right now, my current test for debugging is inputting "x ** 2." when making a user input for *inputFunc*. (Note that I'm currently only working with left Riemann Sums.) However, I get an error when executing the following code:

```
rangeStep = float((inputEnd - inputStart) / inputSum)

def riemannCalc(function):

  sumTotal = 0.

  if inputChoice.lower() in setLRS: #setLRS = ["left", "l"] (described earlier in program)
    for j in calcRange(inputStart, inputEnd, rangeStep): #defined earlier in program - functionally identical to range function except it allows for floats
      x = j
      sumTotal += function * rangeStep
    print(sumTotal)

riemannCalc(inputFunc)
```

I get *TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'* for the line *sumTotal += function * rangeStep*. When debugging, appending the first block of code with the following function...

```
print(inputFunc)
```

returns *x ** 2.*, the same as my user input (even though I had set *x = 0.* earlier in the first block).

This leads me to my question: how can I create a user input or a dynamic variable *x* such that I can manipulate *x* when it is expressed in *inputFunc* (e.g. I set *inputFunc = x ** 2.* and set *x = 4.* to yield *16.0* in the end), especially in the *for loop*?

Comment: Dangerous but simple way is to use `eval()` with a `globals` dictionary containing the `x` with desired value.

Comment: Your `inputFunc` is a string, that's the problem. You want it to be a *function*. Look, creating this sort of calculator is way more difficult than you might expect, especially as a beginners project. You essentially need to implement a parser of sorts. Of course, you can just use `eval`, but then you are just using the Python interpreter

Comment: IOW, taking user input as a string that's supposed to represent a function is non-trivial. You can of course dynamically execute strings as Python code using `eval` or `exec`. And that is trivial, but then there's no point in the exercise

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks for that advice! I was unaware the `eval()` function could do arithmetic. I thought it was only able to distinguish whether a variable was a float, integer, or a string. Also, turns out I only had to add a line `evalFunc = eval(inputFunc)` after `x = j` and then replace `function` with `evalFunc` in the following line.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was aware that`inputFunc` was a string. Perhaps I could've clarified that in my question. Regardless, the trivial `eval()` suits this project just fine since my goal is purely the summation and to get more familiar with loops. After I have more experience with python, I'll at some point create a calculator and then possibly make a revised version of this Riemann Sum calculator.